# Application Package installer has stopped unexpectedly on installation

Tags: android

Hi all. This is my first post on StackOverflow, though I have been making use of this site for a several years. Usually I'm able to find an answer to any queries that I may have, by referring to questions that others have asked; however, in this case I am completely stumped, despite having done quite a bit of homework already

I am currently in the process of developing an Android application which is required to communicate with a piece of hardware - more specifically a PIC32 board - and display data that is returned by the board in real-time.

At present I have simply been using Eclipse and Android emulator for designing the interface and programming the backend of the application. And, I have now gotten to a stage where I would like to test the operation of the application on a physical Android device. However, whenever I attempt to install the application, directly from the phone (I send the .apk via Dropbox) I always get the error **'The application Package installer (process com.android.packageinstaller) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again'**. Now, I have done my homework and seemed to have determined that the error may lie in the Android Manifest file for the application. However, I just cannot see where this issue may be. I have seen other issues resolved by removing certain  tags or replicated  tags; however, even then my application does not want to install on my device, though it installs and works pretty much perfectly everytime when run through the emulator.

The application I am developing is based loosely on the Demo code provided by the hardware manufacturer. It has been appropriately modified. And, when I appropriately modified the Manifest file for my application and tested it with the demo application everything seemed to work fine on a physical device. So, something is telling me that the Manifest file may not actually be the issue. The key differences between my application and the demo application is that I have divided the code up into appropriate packages, such that one contains application code (activities) and the other contains code for communicating with the PIC32 board. I have also added an activity - the demo code only has one, but have two at present. The final difference is that I have defined a global object, for communicating with the board, that can be used by all of the application's activities. However, I don't believe that these would be the cause of this issue.

So again, the application seems to work fine on the emulator, but it simply does not want to install on a physical Android device - everytime I try to install I get an alert dialog box displaying this message.

I would very much appreciate any help and advice that anybody could provide, and thanks in advance.

Also, here is the Manifest file for the application I am developing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tribosonics.android.TribosonicsApp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" >
</uses-sdk>
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" >
</uses-sdk>

<!--
<permissions>
    <feature name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />

    <library
        name="com.android.future.usb.accessory"
        file="/system/framework/com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar" />
</permissions>
-->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".GlobalAccessoryManager"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/tribosonics_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />

    <activity
        android:name=".TribosonicsApp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SetScanPreferences"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "(I send the .apk via Dropbox" What, exactly, does this mean? I usually let the Eclipse system send the application to the phone, are you sure this works, also did you get any logcat output during the failed install process?

Comment: I take the application .apk file, put it on Dropbox, and download it via my Android device; it's just a quick and simple way of transferring the installation file.

Comment: As another thought, you have the intent filter for the usb attach as a child of the application, I would have thought that should be in the activity element.

Comment: The reason I am not currently installing and running the application via Eclipse is because of another small issue that I have - my device is missing the com.android.future.usb library - but this should be sorted tomorrow when I get a buy a new device. However, I don't believe that this is the cause of the Package installer stopping unexpectedly... or could it be? I'll have to come back to this tomorrow when my new phone arrives. Sorry for the trouble, but thanks for the responses.

Comment: Would I need to have that intent filter for every activity that I declare in the Manifest file, or just the main activity that launches when the application is started?

Comment: On the one that is invoked when the accessory described in the meta data is attached, and because you don't have "required=true" I don't think it will stop the installation because the library is not on the device.

Comment: hello you got solution of this problem..?? if yes then how??

Comment: @Dhaval Sodha Parmar: The issue, in my case, was being caused by the line android:name=".GlobalAccessoryManager", which is a global application class. Once I removed this the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

android manifest, icon image is big so please reduce your image icon size and run the application it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this with the following exception in LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28817): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.app/.MyActivity } from ProcessRecord{487978e8 28817:com.android.packageinstaller/10063} (pid=28817, uid=10063) requires android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

I thought the problem was due to some `<uses-permission...>` tags in the manifest but in my case there was an `android:permission="..."` attribute in my manifests `application` tag which seemed to be causing the package manager to get the exception and barff. Deleting this got me going again.

Answer (score 0):

change changing `android:debuggable="true"` to `android:debuggable="false"` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I don't expect that to make any difference, one because that's simply used when, well, debugging, and I added it after I started having this issue anyway. I added `code`android:debuggable="true"`code` so that I could use DDMS to try and Logcat to detemine what the issue was. Tried it anyway, but it made no difference. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Logcat details will be helpful here.

Comment: Sure, I'll post them here; however, I'll have to do that tomorrow when my phone that includes the com.android.future.usb library arrives. I didn't expect this missing library to be the cause of the issue, and so I asked the question to see if I could get back to the stage when I get an installation has failed message instead of the 'application Package installer has stopped unexpectedly' message. Sorry for the trouble, but thanks for the responses. I shall be back tomorrow once I have tested this on my new device.